# Flatsome UX Builder not loading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I just installed the Flatsome theme on my SSL protected site. I was going to use the UX builder to edit the pages but it was not loaded what should I do? Some sites say that it is due to SSL, but I do not know what to do?

What I'm seeing can be seen below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please post more information about what you've tried, what resources you've looked at that tell you `SSL` might be the issue

Comment: have you solved this issue? i also encountered same issue, but even the loading screen does not show up

Comment: I'm copying the link to another answer for the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66566705/6440363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that ajax request is not returning the desired data to render ux Builder. You need investigate wich error is causiing this issue. Check error.log of your server regarding any php error. Also check console of browser If its returning javascript error. Paste errors here

Comment: im trying to post an issue pic but site let me. why my entry is deleting?

Comment: Try using a service like imgbb.com for images. Or pastebin.com for code. These services will host in a third party server and generate a link. Then you can paste the link here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any caching plugin or performance plugins installed . De-activate for a while and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to hosting account.
2. Login to **phpMyAdmin**.
3. Choose the affected database. If you only have one database, it should choose
   it by default so you don’t need to do anything.
4. In the main panel, you should see a list of your database tables. Check the boxes by the tables that need repair. You can use **“Check all”** checkbox just below the list to select all tables.
5. At the bottom of the window just below the list of tables, there is a **drop down** menu. Choose **“Repair Table”**

Answer (score 0):

Check your function.php file, disable or fix javascript function to fix it.