# Wordpress theme Flatsome 3.11: UX Builder not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I've just installed Flatsome theme version 3.11.0, wordpress 5.4, php 7.4, mysql 8.0 on my SSL protected site.

I disable all plugins, not even one.
First, I can edit home page easily. But when I edit other page, like contact, about... it was not loaded.
I checked console, has a error in image 1.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRoot' of undefined
    at t.value (editor.js?ver=3.11.0:2)
```

But I refreshed page while console opened, no error display in image 2. 
That error only show when console closed.

Please help me, thank you so much.

[image: error displayed when open console after load page]
[image: error not display when open console before load page]

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue on various hosting platforms, and the solution has been different. Listing some of those here:

1. If you are using cloudflare, disable cache, preferably enable developer mode, while you are doing the edits
2. If you are using any caching plugin disable those
3. Ensure that you are using the same scheme (http vs https) to serve your site as has been added to your wp-config
4. Reload the page after you've disabled all cache

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and between clearing the cache, and switching to the twenty Twenty theme the problem fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disable catche plugins and it would work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31093447)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and spent hours troubleshooting it.

I solved it by noticing at last that my page had a automatic redirect on url by Rank Math and this prevents UX builder from loading.

If other pages load UX builder but one doesn't, this might be worthwhile to check out.