# There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions is not fixing

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My WordPress website https://poaa.ca/ is not loading and I'm facing a critical error issue for the last two days. I tried many tricks to fix the issue like disabled plugins, themes, and show errors. I added this code to my config file, but still errors not showing. What can I do? Your help will be appreciated.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true )
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true )
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false )
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 )
```

Comment: If you've disabled all the plugins and themes then you might want to try reinstalling WordPress, as that would seem to be the only thing left running at that point. Or check for typos in your config.

Comment: Is the `debug.log` fine not there?

Comment: Actually the issue is debug.log file is here but when I made some error in code and try to check in debug.log file, the errors not showing in debug.log file.

Comment: You should visit this community if you want to troubleshoot WP related issues, as it comes handy and have most recent information about this topic. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352723/how-to-fix-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website-please-check-your-s

Comment: You can use this way I've solved my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71768127/14723812

Comment: You can use this link I've solved my issue with this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71768127/14723812

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you try to Revert to a [Default Theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwenty/). Remove theme and upload WordPress Twenty Twenty theme.
2. Increase PHP memory limit up to 128M - 1G.
3. Update PHP version.

One of these options will [solve your problem](https://techedutricks.com/wordpress/).

Comment: I try so many times but I'm very confused because I don't know what is the error. Debug true also is not working to sgow me the errors.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue,

1. Open your website Cpanel - File Manager
2. Inserted this code in your wp-config.php file to create a Debug Log.

`// Enable WP_DEBUG mode

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );`

it will log all errors, notices, and warnings to a file called debug.log in the wp-content directory. It will also hide the errors so they do not interrupt page generation.

3. Go to the Debug Log file, download, and open the file using a code editor.
4. If the error is from the **post** file, download this [post file](https://fossies.org/linux/www/wordpress-5.9.2.tar.gz/wordpress/wp-includes/post.php?m=b)
5. Replace the file in the directory as shown in your Debug Log file.
6. Refresh your website, and enjoy.
7. Don't forget to go back to step and remove the code you added to Wp_config file